# How do I include a third-party logger formatter in a PasteDeploy ini file?

Tags: python, pyramid, paster

I am trying to utilize Pyramid and pyramid_exclog to send exceptions to a third-party system whenever an exception occurs in my web app.  Unfortunately, I cannot seem to make my PasteDeploy development.ini to properly recognize the formatter.

I've tried several variations, including:

```
[formatter_exc_formatter]
class=JsonFormatter()
```

...

```
[formatter_exc_formatter]
class=jsonlogger.JsonFormatter()
```

...

```
[formatter_exc_formatter]
class=pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter()
```

I have also tried specifying pythonjsonlogger as part of my pyramid_includes, as so:

```
pyramid.includes = pyramid_exclog, pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger
```

as well as just:

```
pyramid.includes = pyramid_exclog, pythonjsonlogger
```

At this point I am pretty stumped.  What am I missing?  How do I include custom formatters into a PasteDeploy-managed app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drop the `()` from your `class` line.

Instead of:

```
[formatter_exc_formatter]
class=pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter()
```

You need to do the following:

```
[formatter_exc_formatter]
class=pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter
```

---

`pythonjsonlogger` is not a Pyramid module and does not have an `includeme()` function which is called by Pyramid for all `pyramid.includes`.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!  I am not sure why I didn't try it without the ()'s but this worked splendidly.